# How to solve permission error when my user is owner of the file and I can't access from administrator user either

Tags: security, encryption, file-permissions, efs

I used Microsoft encryption to encrypt my Office files but now it says you need permission to open this file while opening. I am opening the file with the user which is owner of the files and I have tried opening from administrator account and again it said you don't have permission to decry-pt or anything.

Comment: If the user has accss by NTFS permission but can't open the file the correct EFS certificate (+private key) are missing on the system you are trying to access the files. This can happen if the profile folder was deleted and re-created or a new Windows installation was used to access the file. If the EFS private key has not been saved somewhere you have to use the EFS Recovery Agent account on the system it's recovery key is present (AFAIR the first DC used to set-up the domain).

Comment: @Robert I have the same certificate installed on the system which i have used while encrypting the files.

Comment: Does the certificate also contains the private key? The certificate only allows you to encrypt files, the private key is responsible for decrypting.

Comment: @Robert yes sir i can  attach screen shot of certificate if you want